# Hard time understanding recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
  public static int fun(int n) {
    if (n<=1) return 1;
    else return (n + fun(n-1));   
  }
```

Why does `fun(6)` return `21`?

How I visualize the recursion is as follow:

```
6 + 5 = 11
5 + 4 = 9
4 + 3 = 7
3 + 2 = 5
2 + 1 = 3
1       1
11 + 9 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 1 = 36
```

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here?

-- edit removed the `System.out.println()`, forgot to remove it when i posted the code.

I tried the following on my own:

```
public static int fun(int n) {
    if (n==1) return 2;
    else return 2 * fun(n-1);   
}

2 * fun(4)
2 * (2 * fun(3))
2 * (2 * (2 * fun(2)))
2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * fun(1))))
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 32
```

Is this the right way of visualizing it?

Comment: if java optimized tail recursion `fun(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` would work.

Comment: nhouser9 gives a good overview of each step below. I had same problem originally with recursion but try and think about it in terms of stack frames - your first call to `fun(6)` sits in the first frame, then you make a recursive call to `fun(n-1)` which gets executed in another stack frame. When you get to the end of the recursion - when `n<=1` - then the stack unwinds and the result of each recursive call is passed back to the previous one. So your summing up is in the wrong order in effect.

Comment: @Andreas Java doesn't do tail call optimisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to `fun` ends up doing `return n + fun(n-1);`. So let's step through and see what happens.

You call `fun(6)` which...

evaluates to `6 + fun(5)` which...

evaluates to `6 + (5 + fun(4))` which...

evaluates to `6 + (5 + (4 + fun(3)))` which...

evaluates to `6 + (5 + (4 + (3 + fun(2))))` which...

evaluates to `6 + (5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + fun(1)))))` and since `fun(1) = 1`, this

evaluates to `6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1` which is `21`.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's simpler to visualize it as:

```
fun(6) =
6 + fun(5) =
6 + 5 + fun(4) =
...
6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 =
21
```

Basically each recursive call moves us one step closer to a termination (n <= 1). The final result can only be computed once termination has been reached

Answer (score 1):

```
fun(6) = 6 + fun(5)
       = 6 + 5 + fun(4)
       = 6 + 5 + 4 + fun(3)
       ...
       = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21
```

Answer (score 1):

First line "System.out.println(n + " " + (n-1));" shows only the values of variable 'n' and DOESN'T CONTAIN ANY ARITHMETIC OPERATIONS.

Steps of this function:

6>1 so: 6 + fun(5),

5>1 so: 6 + 5 + fun(4),

4>1 so: 6 + 5 + 4 + fun(3),

3>1 so: 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + fun(2),

2>1 so: 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + fun(1),

1>=1 so: 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

and the SUM of: 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21

I hope my explanation will be useful for you.